# .htaccess redirection for alias domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have two domains named **www.example.com** and **www.example-alias.com** ,
Both domain are pointing same location in the server.
I need to do 301 redirection for www.example.com to www.example-alias.com

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On        
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example-alias.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It is working only for www.example.com home page, not for any inner page.
How do I redirect www.example.com inner pages to www.example-alias.com.
Similar

```
www.example.com/service to www.example-alias.com/service
```

Comment: What does happen when you visit www.example.com/service?

Answer (score 0):

I ca not test it now, but try this out.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example-alias.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example-alias.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```